# Docker-compose 3.7 multi-platform configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, buildx

I have just started new AWS t4g linux/arm64 instance and I am having a trouble running docker image on it.

I am using docker-compose.yml version 3.7 and I use gitlab CI runners to build the image.
I have read the official documentation but its a bit confusing when it comes to what actually works, because I have tried several methods to build the image for linux/arm64 but none of it worked so far.

In [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/mixing-windows-and-linux-containers-with-docker-compose/), it says that `--platform` is not supported in `docker-compose.yml v3` and in [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/) it says `buildx` should be included in 19.3 version (I assume it should work for 19.3 and newer, since my actual Docker engine version is 20.10.3), but nothing works.

This is my gitlab-ci.yml for building ELK (elastic stack), which fails since `--platform` is not supported here I guess.

```
docker-build-elk:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker/compose
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker info
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    # pull dev image for caching
    - docker pull ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:elk || true
    - docker-compose -f ./elk/docker-compose.elastic.yml build --platform linux/arm64
  after_script:
    - docker push ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:elk
  only:
    - elk
```

I also tried to use ENVs with

```
 - docker-compose -f ./elk/docker-compose.elastic.yml build --build-arg DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 --build-arg COMPOSE_DOCKER_CLI_BUILD=1
```

Since it was reported as bug for v3, is there a way to get it working / or build image for arm64?